# How to remove red lines in the top right corner of a window in KDE?

Tags: kde, window, appearance

Here is a screenshot of what I want to remove (small red lines), but I can't find out how.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Which KDE are you using and do the red lines also appear when you use a different window scheme (like oxygen for example)? Do they appear in all applications?

Comment: @fifaltra Kubuntu 14.04.02,kade version 4.13.3, application appearance -> style -> qtcurve , workspace appearance -> window decorations->Evolvere Light. the red lines do not appear i drew them for illustration, which space i want to remove.

Comment: Then I think you should revert the edit, because your question at the moment is "how to remove red lines"